# VB 6.0 unable to create array

Tags: arrays, vba, vb6

I am not able to create an array in VB 6.0 and I'm going crazy trying to figure it out. First of all VB is not my native language, I am a PHP programmer so arrays are not a new concept for me... Hopefully someone can help with this.

This is my function:

```
Function get_plant() As String

Dim arrPlant(1 To 10) As String
arrPlant(1) = "PL1"
arrPlant(2) = "PL2"
arrPlant(3) = "PL3"
arrPlant(4) = "PL4"
arrPlant(5) = "PL5"
arrPlant(6) = "PL6"
arrPlant(7) = "PL7"
arrPlant(8) = "PL8"
arrPlant(9) = "PL9"
arrPlant(10) = "PL0"

get_plant = arrPlant

End Function
```

Then I tried calling it with this (and about 10 other variations...):

```
Dim plant_code() As String
plant_code = get_plant()
MsgBox plant_code(1)
```

When I try and use the array I get this:
[Question mark in the array index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rSO9.png)

What the heck am I missing here?

Comment: The function is declared as `String` but you are trying to return a string *array*.

Comment: `Function get_plant() As String()`

Comment: omg that was it... THANK YOU!!!

Comment: There's a reason why PHP is pronounced "poop."  And for that matter it isn't a programming language but a scripting language, making you a poop scripter.

Comment: I think you're reaching a bit there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the function you have given is `string` not `string()` and you are trying to return string array. Try giving this

```
Function get_plant() As String()
```